# Active Record (Object doesn't support #inspect) in includes method

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, activerecord, associations

Here is my MySQL database schema:

```
create table url (
  id int(11) primary key,
  url text,
  url_md5 char(32),
  urlpath text,
  cleanurl text,
  title text
);

create table record (
  id int(11) primary key,
  uid varchar(25),
  url text,
  url_md5 char(32)
);

create table user (
  uid varchar(25) primary key
);
```

And this is a legacy project, so the schema created before i use active recorad. My ruby code is just like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'user'

  has_many :records, class_name: 'Record', 
           foreign_key: 'uid', primary_key: 'uid'

  def self.cached_count
    @cached_count ||= User.count
  end
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'record'

  has_one :urldetail, class_name: 'Url',
          foreign_key: 'url_md5', primary_key: 'url_md5',
          select: [:urlpath, :cleanurl]
end

class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'url'

  belongs_to :record, class_name: 'Record',
             primary_key: 'url_md5', foreign_key: 'url_md5'
end
```

It looks a little complicated. The `url` and `record` table create association by `url_md5` and the `record` table and `user` table create association by `uid`. They are not the primary keys. And when I use `includes` it shows error like this:

```
2.0.0-p247 :003 > u.records.includes(:urldetail)
D, [2013-10-30T20:08:33.207225 #47431] DEBUG -- :   Record Load (9.3ms)  SELECT `record`.* FROM `record` WHERE `record`.`uid` = '5669408714090543819'
D, [2013-10-30T20:08:33.303839 #47431] DEBUG -- :   Url Load (45.7ms)  SELECT urlpath, cleanurl FROM `url` WHERE `url`.`url_md5` IN ('2029708d8c99a3f781b6d695ddedf80c', '977434e3d3b080971d67b6a5c3850d57', '784820ccc528cc3a3cf2df3b677f8761', '14eea8c73d7dab59dbdd6f2d5c19eaed', 'dfb5ea7bbca8018d5bf7aedf4f03df1f', 'aad852910d0f6d1c96fa82e99399800d', '873a263e4bcd28f9e95e150a746c1188')
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
 =>
```

I googled the problem but get nothing.

---

*Update*

If I write `u.records.includes(:urldetail).to_a` then the result will be:

```
    SELECT urlpath, cleanurl FROM `url` WHERE `url`.`url_md5` IN ('2029708d8c99a3f781b6d695ddedf80c', '977434e3d3b080971d67b6a5c3850d57', '784820ccc528cc3a3cf2df3b677f8761', '14eea8c73d7dab59dbdd6f2d5c19eaed', 'dfb5ea7bbca8018d5bf7aedf4f03df1f', 'aad852910d0f6d1c96fa82e99399800d', '873a263e4bcd28f9e95e150a746c1188')
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: url_md5
```

But I do have column `url_md5`.

Comment: try `u.records.includes(:urldetail).to_a`

Comment: @tihom And there will be a new error: `missing attribute: url_md5`. Why is that.